# How to simulate .click() on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I need to click a div to do an action.
I do desktop version succesfully, but when I go to mobile, click action does not work. **I try several ways that found here in Stack Overflow and other websites**, but any works...

My code for desktop:

```
document.getElementById('BtMisDocumentos').click();
```

My code for mobile (3 attempts);

```
$('BtMisDocumentos').trigger('vclick');
$('BtMisDocumentos').trigger('tap');
$('BtMisDocumentos').trigger('touchstart');
```

Div;

```
<div id="BtMisDocumentos" class="dx-button dx-button-normal dx-button-mode-text dx-widget dx-button-has-text" onclick="void(0)" role="button" aria-label="Mis Documentos" style="width: 140px;"><div class="dx-button-content"><span class="dx-button-text">Mis Documentos</span></div></div>
```

Any idea? maybe does not work, because I am using a user agent, despite of a "real" mobile?

Comment: It is very important that you also mention what mobile, OS, OS version and mobile browser & version are you testing this on, where the logic is not working?

Comment: Thanks! Im testing on Chrome 83.0, using a iPhoneX user agent.

Comment: The event should be the same. Mobile browsers usually use a virtual event to then trigger the `click` event. Look at TouchPunch or jQuery Mobile for some hints. Also your selectors do not look correct.

Comment: Typo: `$('BtMisDocumentos')` -> `$('#BtMisDocumentos')`. Also, depending on how the event handler you're trying to trigger is bound, you may need to raise a native click event: `$element[0].click()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing something:

```
//Use a . for a element class and # for a element id. Use it in the $('#...') part.
$('.BtMisDocumentos').trigger('vclick');
$('#BtMisDocumentos').trigger('tap');
$('.BtMisDocumentos').trigger('touchstart');
```

Try this with .click() aswell.

jQuery docs:
https://api.jquery.com/click/

**EDIT @TWISTY:**

If you want to just copy and paste:

```
//With a HTML class attribute. Example: <div class="BtMisDocumentos"></div>
$('.BtMisDocumentos').trigger('vclick');
$('.BtMisDocumentos').trigger('tap');
$('.BtMisDocumentos').trigger('touchstart');
$('.BtMisDocumentos').click();

//With a HTML id attribute. Example: <div id="BtMisDocumentos"></div>
$('#BtMisDocumentos').trigger('vclick');
$('#BtMisDocumentos').trigger('tap');
$('#BtMisDocumentos').trigger('touchstart');
$('#BtMisDocumentos').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery versus JavaScript, you will use CSS Style Selectors.

```
$('#BtMisDocumentos').trigger('vclick');
$('#BtMisDocumentos').trigger('tap');
$('#BtMisDocumentos').trigger('touchstart');
```

For your code, the following should work still on Mobile:

```
$('#BtMisDocumentos').click();
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: @Allart you're using the Class selector when OP never mentioned a Class attribute.

Comment: I gave an example of how it could be done, in the hope he and others would understand... If you can, tell me which part is unclear so I can change it. Or maybe ask for an edit request on my answer :)

Comment: @Allart it is better to clarify that you are giving an example using both the Class selector as well as the ID selector. If OP had used your answer exactly, some of the items would not have worked properly due to a lack of elements with the `BtMisDocumentos` class. This is misleading to OP and others. If I wanted to edit your answer, I wouldn't need to ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: How about this :D @Twisty